# How flexible is the tolerance on jointer blade sizes?

Tags: jointer, blade

I recently inherited an old 4” PowrKraft jointer, from the early 50s. I measured the old blades with digital calipers and found that they are 4” x 0.71” x 0.11”.

I can’t find a reliable source on what size the blades should be, let alone a supplier. Is it generally safe to use shorter blades?

Are there any good resources for learning more about old jointers or are there any modern suppliers that might have appropriate blades?

I found replacement blades that measure 4” x 0.62” x 0.12”. Do you think these are a near enough fit? It’s a Powrkraft TRT 2514.

Edit: I believe this might be the original manual, and it does not specify a blade size. http://vintagemachinery.org/pubs/657/18077.pdf

Comment: Since up/down can obviously be adjusted for in a jointer (and in more than one way) it should easily allow for variation in blade width (height?); might be different if the new ones were taller, but shorter should be no problem. I'd say blade thickness is probably the critical dimension, and I can't imagine 1/100" discrepancy can't be taken up by excess screw travel..... and if absolutely needed the screws could be ground shorter to make this possible.

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that they weren't to particular about the blade sizes, They didn't have the same tolerances in manufacturing we have today, Pretty sure anything that is reasonably close will work with some adjustment.  You should also be able to have the original blades sharpened.

Answer (score 4):

Powr-Kraft tools were distributed by Montgomery Ward in the 1930s through the 80s and manufactured by various companies. If you have the serial numbers, etc. you might be able to deduce who made the jointer based on this resource and thereby acquire similar replacements: [http://vintagemachinery.org/mfgindex/detail.aspx?id=657][1]](http://vintagemachinery.org/mfgindex/detail.aspx?id=657%5D%5B1%5D)

I think the part number for the blades is 842521. You might get further looking for that specifically. I can't find a source for parts, and you're right, they're not too informative about the knife specifications...

There are also woodworking forums that might have some members who are into "old time" tool restorations and could provide more specific information or at least point you in the right direction. You might find someone who has worked with one of those models (or similar) at https://lumberjocks.com and/or https://sawmillcreek.com and/or others...

Also, while not really meaning to make a "shopping recommendation", the people at https://mywoodcutters.com are pretty good at figuring this kind of stuff out. It might be worth shooting them an email.

Comment: Shopping Qs are not allowed, shopping recommendations are :-)

Comment: @Graphus In that case, a box of money always makes a great gift... color goes with everything, size is always spot on, nobody can have too many, etc.